# Social effect of ability to predict the date but not the occasion

Tags: society, near-future, psychology

I have an idea about a person, who knows exact date and time of significant future events. But does not know what is going to happen. And the dates such person knows are significant for culture that person is inside:

Example: That person knows exact date and time when new president of USA is going to be elected/announced (meaning the exact date and time after counting of the votes when the rival is going to step up and say: "I lost").

But true name of president of USA is unknown for that person.

Also, if there is civil war going on in Zambia and no one inside USA cares, as long as that person is inside USA, he does not know even the date of next bloody event. But once that person travels to Zambia, he instantly knows the date (but still not the event)

That person knows all the significant dates up to one year to the future. Of course, some events are guessable (as of presidential elections), but sometimes you have to wait and see what happens on 4th November 2016, 21:30

The dates are "significant" in a way where more than 60% of population of such culture would speak about the event. Which means, you have predictions both about terrorist attacks and say some hollywood class star announcing publically their sexuality.

**Is there something positive you can do with such ability?**

Especially if such significant dates for the USA can also be terrorist attacks in Paris (I assume more than 60% of Americans did care about the event), so you can trigger homeland security over "nothing"

Comment: Are these future events alterable? If they somehow determine that a terrorist attack will occur, can they actually prevent it? And if so, will he immediately know when the event has been prevented, because now his next significant date has changed?

Comment: I suspect that some very large percentage of the dates this person has "foresight" about are not very surprising. For example, he will have a "feeling" about election day, perhaps the day after election day, Super Bowl Sunday, etc.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to say in the question. If Justin Bieber's new haircut will cause at least 60 percent of Americans speaking of it, this person will know the date of him announcing his haircut...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An interesting question: and one for which I think the answer is yes, but only with some serious high level support.

Firstly: Notices from this person can be used to inform security services about impending threats. If they cross-reference their information with his prediction of dates, then it becomes quite the tool for knowing when additional security may be required.

Secondly: Your post indicates that there's a geographical component to this power. I'm going to assume that it's not exactly split along country lines (as what a Texan cares about may not be what a New Yorker cares about), but that it instead works on proximity. At this point you can use the guy (for some events, at least) as a proximity sensor. Again: Cross reference this information and you help out a lot of security services, but you'll need to move him around a *lot*.

Thirdly: The cultural component, depending on how you break it down, can be of incredible use. If this man is isolated with a group of 9 year olds, and that affects his power, then sitting him in a room with 400 intelligence analysis and letting him soak up the cultural quirks of the spooks is going to skew which events he picks up on. They might not care about the results of the next baseball game, but they do care about the assassination attempt at a national conference the day after. If the geographical component is the main deal here, however, then this takes a back seat somewhat.

For example. The man throws out a date that the US security services say 'ah, we think a terrorist organisation from Madeupistan is planning something around those dates' They put this man on a plane, fly him over Madeupistan and see if the date is the same there as it is in the US. If it is, then they can be pretty certain that the event in question is one that Madeupistan will care about, and they should increase security. If not then they can assume that it will be a piece of celebrity dross that no-one outside the US will care about.

This effect can even be exploited with friendly countries, as the next major event the UK will care about might not be the same as the US if it's anything that's not an international incident. Of course: false positives such as 'Celebrity X announces shock pregnancy!' might bridge the gap, but you can narrow down your parameters quite successfully using this technique.

Of course: Your guy is going to be constantly jet lagged and essentially a prisoner of various TLO's, but he'll be helping!

Comment: Sounds basically like [Minority Report](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181689/)

Comment: That's basically because it's a less accurate version of Minority Report!

Comment: If 60% of the people in Madeupistan actually know about the plans for a terrorist attack, and are "talking about it", it is unlikely that we would not already have more concrete information through our existing un-psychic intelligence network

Comment: @DSKekaha: It doesn't matter if they know about the plans, it matters that they'll care about the news that someone from Madeupistan was involved, which I imagine 60% of the population will (for a variety of reasons). The future is full of people talking about the secret plans of the past.

Comment: @JoeBloggs Oh you're absolutely right, I was reading the Question too fast.  60% of Madeupistanians WILL talk about the event once it happens.

Answer (score 3):

To stay in the spirit of the question, what can be done without trying to determine the nature of the event?

- Just before the next event, buy financial instruments which "bet on instability" like gold or certain weird derivatives. You can make money on a stock which goes down, if you guessed right ...
- After some years, the character will have made enough money to make significant donations for his or her favorite cause.

Comment: And if one of the events is a terror attack and someone notices you bought those financial instruments, you'll find yourself on the list of terror suspects (and possibly in consequence on the no-fly list, if not worse).

Comment: @celtschk that's still better than being a terror suspect because you told in advance that «something important will happen on Sep 11»